# What file(s) contain project settings for Android Studio 2.2?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.1, android-studio-2.2

I'm new to Android development (and to gradle), as is our small team. We have one developer who has been working on a project for a couple weeks, and who has been checking their code into GitHub periodically.

When I download their code and attempt to open in Android Studio 2.2, I get asked about various project settings. This surprised me, because it seems that all the project settings *should* already be specified somewhere in a file saved in the project settings. My coworker ought to be able to save all of their project configuration settings into the project file, upload it to the repository, and I should be able to download all of his files and simply build and run the project on my machine, assuming we're running the same version of Android Studio and both have the same SDK(s) installed.

My question is, what file(s) contain the project settings under Android Studio 2.2 and 2.1 (the version he started development with)? I've tried searching online and here on stack overflow for **"what file contains project settings in android studio"**. However, this only gets me results that talk about what a project is, and what dialog boxes contain certain settings. I'd like to know which files (gradle, xml, etc) files contain the project settings (build, SDK, workspace, etc).

I've also tried uninstalling 2.2 and going back to 2.1.2, but that doesn't help much either. In both cases, I'm getting questions about project settings as well as build errors. I don't want to address all of those issues here though.

Thanks so much for you help!

Comment: The project settings can be found within the `.idea` directory located in the root project directory.

Comment: I forgot, there is also the `.iml` file in the project root that contains project specific settings.

Answer (score 1):

From the location where you have installed Android Studio,

you will have something like `.AndroidStudio2.2` folder this contains settings for version `AndroidStudio2.2`

What you do is Unistall studio and installng new one(AndroidStudio2.2), it will ask you to take settings from just give this path mentioned.

**Other than this,**

your `gradle` file will have all settings of your project.

it will be of module level and project level.

Comment: Project specific settings shouldn't be located in the general user-wide AndroidStudio settings.

Comment: i do know that @Robert that is why i have mentioned about gradle in separate way.